# Is openmp included in stdio.h in c/c++？

Tags: c++, c, openmp

I searched about openmp, and realised that some people includes omp.h and others do not. They just include stdio.h.

So my question is: Is openmp included in stdio.h so that we can use opemp if we only include it?

I think old openmp such as openmp2.0 need to be used with omp.h but openmp3.0 does not need to be so.
but I'm not sure...

Comment: i don't think it ever is in `stdio.h` - its up to the compiler and its base libraries

Comment: I think it's compiler specific

Comment: Note: There is no rule saying that one header cannot include another header or that it must include another header. If you always include the correct headers  for all of the "stuff" your code uses, you will have fewer surprises.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`stdio.h` does not contain `omp.h`.

Your confusion may be because to use `#pragma omp ...` directives you do not have to include `omp.h`, so it means that you can write an OpenMP program without including `omp.h`.

On the other hand, if you use any OpenMP runtime library function (e.g. `omp_get_num_threads()`) you have to include `omp.h` regardless of the version of OpenMP.